# How to trace a NaN in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, floating-point

I am going to do some math calculations using C++ .  The input floating point number is a valid number, but after the calculations, the resulting value is NaN. I would like to trace the point where NaN value appears (possibly using GDB), instead of inserting a lot of `isNan()` into the code.  But I found that even code like this will not trigger an exception when a NaN value appears.

```
double dirty = 0.0;
double nanvalue = 0.0/dirty;
```

Could anyone suggest a method for tracing the NaN or turning a NaN into an exception?

Comment: Related: [Can I make gcc tell me when a calculation results in NaN or inf at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941611/can-i-make-gcc-tell-me-when-a-calculation-results-in-nan-or-inf-at-runtime/20973509)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393997/stopping-the-debugger-when-a-nan-floating-point-number-is-produced

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can use the _controlfp function to set the behavior of floating-point calculations (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh(VS.80).aspx).  Maybe there is a similar variant for your platform.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately my platform is GCC4.1 , Centos 5.5 Linux.  I am still trying to figure out how to achieve the same thing in Linux with GCC

Comment: feenableexcept()  seems working, I am now trying to trace my program with this.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/g77/Floating-point-Exception-Handling.html#Floating-point%20Exception%20Handling

Answer (score 41):

Since you mention using gdb, here's a solution that works with gcc -- you want the
functions defined in `fenv.h` :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   double dirty = 0.0;

   feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);  // Enable all floating point exceptions but FE_INEXACT
   double nanval=0.0/dirty;
   printf("Succeeded! dirty=%lf, nanval=%lf\n",dirty,nanval);
}
```

Running the above program produces the output "Floating point exception".  Without
the call to `feenableexcept`, the "Succeeded!" message is printed.

If you were to write a signal handler for `SIGFPE`, that might be a good place to
set a breakpoint and get the traceback you want. (Disclaimer: haven't tried it!)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I just want to point out that enabling *all* the floating point exceptions enables also FE_INEXACT which happens very often (even for: float f = 0.1) and the debug becomes impossible. Is much better to use feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO| FE_INVALID|FE_OVERFLOW);

Comment: Here's a useful page for OS X, which doesn't include feenableexcept: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~williams/archive/computation/fe-handling-example.c

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on floating point programming can be found on http://ds9a.nl/fp/ including the difference between 1/0 and 1.0/0 etc, and what a NaN is and how it acts.

Answer (score 0):

One can enable so-called "signaling NaN". That should make it easily possible to make the debugger find the correct position.

Via google, I found this for enabling signaling NaNs in C++, no idea if it works:

`std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN();`

[Usefulness of signaling NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247447/usefulness-of-signaling-nan)

Comment: That expression evaluates to a signaling NaN, but I think pagedown is more interested in forcing a floating point exception for operations that return NaN, which would probably be a platform-specific compiler option, or runtime configuration of the FP processor.

Comment: Ah sorry. I understood it as making all NaN signaling.

Comment: Thank you very much. My platform is GCC4.1 , Centos 5.5 Linux 
I am going to take a look at the compiler options :)