# Stopping the debugger when a NaN floating point number is produced

Tags: c++, gdb, floating-point, nan

I have an C++ program. Somewhere in the program (hard to reproduce, but reproduceable) a caclculation results in a float beeing set to a NaN. Since a floating point operation involving a NaN results in a NaN, this spreads fast.

Is there any way I can setup the compiler (gcc 4.4) or the debuger (gdb) to stop when a floating point operation results in a NaN? That would be extremely useful.

Thanks!
Nathan

PS: It might matter: I am working under ubuntu linux 10.10.

Comment: You could enable floating point exceptions, just in debug mode.  Check your CRT, not sure how it is done in yours.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615724/how-to-trace-a-nan-in-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could enable floating point exceptions - see [glibc Control Functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Control-Functions.html) - then you'll get a `SIGFPE` when your `NaN` value is produced

Comment: feenableexcept(FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW); Does the trick, thank you!

Comment: The answer is correct. However on OSX you need something like this http://www-personal.umich.edu/~williams/archive/computation/fe-handling-example.c because feenableexcept() is not available.

Comment: dont forget to add #include <fenv.h> while using feenableexcept()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `feenableexcept` like so:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  // Values at: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/FE_OVERFLOW/
  feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<(i/0.)<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```