# Debug C++ code: Catch first NaN appearance

Tags: c++, debugging, nan

Is there a simple way to check a C++ code in a debugger for the very first appearance of a NaN value?

Comment: First appearance in what respect? Within an array, vector, algorithm or something else?

Comment: To make my question clear: In my large and complicated code, a matrix is generated that contains some NaNs. My problem is to trace back where the very first NaN was created.

Comment: Can you specify how you fill the matrix? If it gets filled dynamically, then you could change data type of matrix member representing single number to be some class. Then you overload its `operator = (float f)`. And inside overload you put assert for NaN. Would that work?

Comment: okay: there is already a discussion to it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5393997/1326595

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5394095/1326595

Just include

```
#include <fenv.h>
```

and than add the following line to the code:

```
feenableexcept(FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
```

The debugger is than able to capture the signal and shows the very first occurrence of a NaN.

Comment: Depending on your environment, you might need to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE ` above the include

Answer (score 5):

By IEEE standard the following condition is `false` for `NaN`'s:

```
val == val
```

and you could use it to trigger assert or software breakpoint, but beware of compiler optimizations. Probably, in debug build it would not get optimized away

Comment: If the standard says val == val should be false for NaN's, then it should _not_ be optimized. An optimization here would be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Yes-yes, you must have read the same thread. There were multitudes of opinions. Someone suggested to declare `val` volatile to feel extra safe. I just could not find it..

Comment: I know how to check whether a value is NaN or not. But my question is, how to check where the very first NaN was created. The problem is that my final matrix has some NaNs, and now I have to trace back through a very large code where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an `assert(val >= 0 || val <= 0)` to catch a NaN

Comment: simpler perhaps would be `assert(val == val)`

Comment: I guess Andrew's solution is more optimizer-proof