# Why is GDB backtrace limited when using floating point control?

Tags: gdb

Following the advice of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393997/stopping-the-debugger-when-a-nan-floating-point-number-is-produced) I added `#include <fenv.h>` and `feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);` to my main source and compiled it using `g++ -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g main.cpp -o main.o`.  All files in the project are compiled this way using make.  `feenableexcept` was only added to main.  Things are linked together with the same -O0 and -g.  I then run the executable as `gdb a.out`.  The debugger gives me the expected `SIGFPE` however backtrace doesn't provide the normally useful information.  Instead I get a listing like this:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00002aaaabe19c0d in _amd_handle_error () from /lib64/libm.so.6
(gdb) bt                                                        
#0  0x00002aaaabe19c0d in _amd_handle_error () from /lib64/libm.so.6
#1  0x00002aaaabe19cca in _pow_special () from /lib64/libm.so.6     
#2  0x00002aaaabdf6c12 in pow () from /lib64/libm.so.6              
#3  0xbfc971b779361ea1 in ?? ()                                     
#4  0x3fe85bf701f137d7 in ?? ()                                     
#5  0x3fe914100cd71275 in ?? ()                                     
#6  0x00007fffffffa420 in ?? ()                                     
#7  0x00007fffffff9960 in ?? ()                                     
#8  0x3fe7c514ca0e522d in ?? ()                                     
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

If I try to look at the frames I get nothing useful.  In this case the function `pow` is used many times in the area of code with the floating point error.  Knowing how I got to `pow` is the missing information here.

Normally when I use `-O0` and `-g` I get functions, files and line numbers associated with the trace.  If I set a breakpoint using the same executable and backtrace from the breakpoint I get useful information.

```
Breakpoint 1, SurfaceModel::ProcessGroups (this=0x7fffffff9f30) at source/SurfaceModel.cpp:398
398             vector<Group>::iterator it;
(gdb) bt
#0  SurfaceModel::ProcessGroups (this=0x7fffffff9f30) at source/SurfaceModel.cpp:398
#1  0x00000000006768e6 in MainLoop (logFile=...) at source/main.cpp:94
#2  0x0000000000676337 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffbe18) at source/main.cpp:41
```

I then added a `*(int*)0=0;` to the code to force a seg fault to see if this was related to signals.  I got out useful information there as well.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000061f42a in SurfaceModel::ClearGroupHeatRates (this=0x7fffffff9f30) at source/SurfaceModel.cpp:456
456             *(int*)0=0; // force a seg fault
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000061f42a in SurfaceModel::ClearGroupHeatRates (this=0x7fffffff9f30) at source/SurfaceModel.cpp:456
#1  0x0000000000676ba5 in MainLoop (logFile=...) at source/pilager.cpp:137
#2  0x0000000000676341 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffbe18) at source/pilager.cpp:41
```

This seems to be related only to what I did with floating point control.  I am running GDB 7.12 and this was compiled with GCC 5.3.0.  Is there a way to preserve the trace information with `SIGFPE`?

Comment: What version of GLIBC are you using, and what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to preserve the trace information with SIGFPE?

The trace info has ~nothing to do with which signal is being raised, and ~everything to do with the function it is raised in.

Somehow your `pow` is missing unwind descriptor (which is what GDB uses to unwind the stack).

This often happens with assembly-level implementations (where the developer neglects to put in the appropriate `.cfi` directives), or when building code with broken compilers.

The broken compiler seems unlikely, and I can't find any recent versions of GLIBC that used assembly to implement `pow`.

To recover the stack, the following techniques may work:

1. Use reverse debugger (such as [rr](https://rr-project.org/)) and go backwards from the `SIGFPE`. This is the best solution, but I doubt `rr` is available for your (apparently quite old) system.
2. Count the number of times `pow` is called before the crash:

   `(gdb) break pow
   (gdb) commands 1
   silent
   cont
   end
   (gdb) run
     # run until SIGFPE
   (gdb) info break`

   You will now know how many times `pow` was called before the crash.
   Run the program again, ignoring the breakpoint `$N-1` times (you'll need to remove commands from the breakpoint first and use GDB `ignore 1 $N-1` command). You should now be stopped just before the crash, and since you are still not inside `pow`, GDB should have no trouble showing you the stack trace.
   This approach only works if your program is deterministic.