# Stopping the debugger when a NaN floating point number is produced without a code change

Tags: c++, c, nan, sigfpe

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615724/how-to-trace-a-nan-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393997/stopping-the-debugger-when-a-nan-floating-point-number-is-produced/5394095#5394095). The quintessence is that one can throw a SIGFPE if a nan is produced by including fenv.h and enabling  all floating point exceptions but `FE_INEXACT` by `feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);`

Thus, the code changes form

```
int main () {
   double dirty = 0.0;
   double nanvalue = 0.0/dirty;
   return 0;
 }
```

to

```
 #include <fenv.h>
 int main () {
     feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);  // Enable all floating point exceptions but FE_INEXACT
     double dirty = 0.0;
     double nanvalue = 0.0/dirty;
     return 0;
 }
```

This works fine, but you have to change the code. I have the problem, that in a huge c and c++ code base, somewhere a nan is produced and I don't know where. It is not an option to apply the above change to hunderts of files and 
track the error.

Is there a way to enable the all floating point exceptions, WITHOUT a code change? Is there a compile option I am not aware of?

We use the intel icc version 15.0.3 compiler.

Comment: You just need to apply the code change *once*, at the first line of `main()` right?

Comment: I will try it. I thought that I need to include it everywhere.

Comment: As `feenableexcept()` changes the behaviour of the run-time system it needs to be called once only to take global effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter how many files your code spans, you only need to add `feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT)` *once* only, at the first line of your `main()` function.

It will enable the exceptions for your whole program until you disable the exceptions by calling another function such as `fedisableexcept()`.