# NAN -> distinguish between a division by zero and an exponent with a very large negative value

Tags: c++, nan, sigfpe

I included a [check for nan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170464/stopping-the-debugger-when-a-nan-floating-point-number-is-produced-without-a-cod) in my testsuite.

Now a SIGFPE is thrown at the following line

```
const double retVal =exp(exponent);
```

The exponent has a value of approximately value -4000. This is of course very near to zero and without the nan check the calculation goes on with zero.

The signal SIGFPE is now been thrown. I assume that this is a [denormal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001910/what-is-this-denormal-data-about-c) (represented as NAN).

How can I distinguish between a division by zero and an exponent with a very large negative value?

In the second case, doing further calculations with zero works in my case, since I do not need to distinguish between +0 and -0.

EDIT:
I tried what @user2079303 suggested. My code looks like this

```
#include <signal.h>
void fpe_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    switch(info->si_code) {
        case FPE_INTDIV: // division by zero
            break;
        case FPE_FLTUND: // underflow
            break;
        // other cases ...
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction action = {};
    action.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = fpe_handler;
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &action, NULL);
    const double a = 0.0/0.0;
    if (a>0) 
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

This compiles, but does not throw a signal or an error message.

Comment: According to [this `std::exp` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp) valid ranges for a `double` argument is -708.4 to 709.8. Your exponent is clearly much out of that range, probably out of the range of `long double` as well.

Comment: But is is also stated that `If the argument is -∞, +0 is returned`. What is about the gap between -inf and -708.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, from C++ perspective, division by zero has undefined behaviour, so there is no standard way to handle it.

---

In the ubiquitous IEEE 754 standard division by zero is well defined, and will not raise a signal. It is possible to test whether a previously performed calculation divided by zero using the `<cfenv>` header:

```
std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
// do calculation here
if(std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)) {
    // I was just divided by zero. The sky is falling.
    std::abort();
} else if(std::fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW)) {
    // I just underflowed. This is my life now.
}
```

---

Now, dividing a normal floating point number with zero does not raise a signal unless you ask it to using `feenableexcept` (this is a GNU extension; non-standard).

There is no way to distinguish different reasons for SIGFPE in standard C++. But there is [a way in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html) standard:

```
void fpe_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    switch(info->si_code) {
        case FPE_FLTDIV: // division by zero
            break;
        case FPE_FLTUND: // underflow
            break;
        // other cases ...
    }
}

// registering
struct sigaction action = {};
action.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
action.sa_sigaction = fpe_handler;
sigaction(SIGFPE, &action, NULL);
```

Comment: @schorsch312 I expanded my answer with something that is probably more relevant. Dividing a normal floating point number by zero will not raise a SIGFPE.

Comment: The signal handling example is also now fixed with correct type for floating point division by zero.