# How to distinguish different types of NaN float in Python

Tags: python, windows, com, interop, nan

I'm writing Python 2.6 code that interfaces with [NI TestStand](http://www.ni.com/teststand/) 4.2 via COM in Windows. I want to make a "NAN" value for a variable, but if I pass it `float('nan')`, TestStand displays it as `IND`.

Apparently TestStand distinguishes between floating point "IND" and "NAN" values. According to [TestStand help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370052H-01/tssuppref/infotopics/special_constant_values/):

- `IND` corresponds to *Signaling NaN* in Visual C++, while
- `NAN` corresponds to *QuietNaN*

That implies that Python's `float('nan')` is effectively a *Signaling NaN* when passed through COM. However, from what I've read about *Signaling NaN*, it seems that *Signaling NaN* is a bit "exotic" and *Quiet NaN* is your "regular" NaN. So I have my doubts that Python would be passing a *Signaling NaN* through COM. **How could I find out if a Python `float('nan')` is passed through COM as a *Signaling NaN* or *Quiet NaN*, or maybe *Indeterminate*?**

Is there any way to make a *Signaling NaN* versus *QuietNaN* or *Indeterminate* in Python, when interfacing with other languages? (Using `ctypes` perhaps?) I assume this would be a platform-specific solution, and I'd accept that in this case.

**Update:** In the TestStand sequence editor, I tried making two variables, one set to `NAN` and the other set to `IND`. Then I saved it to a file. Then I opened the file and read each variable using Python. In both cases, Python reads them as a `nan` float.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? You may be over complicating things. You could use a NoneType perhaps...

Comment: I want to set a variable to `NAN` (rather than `IND`) in TestStand, via COM using Python. It will be easier to document for the end-user if we can consistently use `NAN` throughout our system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dug a bit for you, and I think you might be able to use the `struct` module in combination with the information on at [Kevin's Summary Charts](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs341/IEEE-754references.html#kevin_chart). They explain the exact bit patterns used for the various kinds of IEEE 754 floating point numbers.

The only thing you probably will have to be careful for, if I read the topics on this `IND`-eterminate value, is that that value tends to trigger some kind of floating point interrupt when assigned directly in C code, causing it to be turned into a plain NaN. Which in turn meant those people were advised to do this kind of thing in ASM rather than C since C abstracted that stuff away.. Since it is not my field, and that I am not sure to what extent this kind of value would mess with Python, I figured I'd mention it so you can at least keep an eye for any such weird behaviour. (See the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247447/usefulness-of-signaling-nan)).

```
>>> import struct

>>> struct.pack(">d", float('nan')).encode("hex_codec")
'fff8000000000000'

>>> import scipy
>>> struct.pack(">d", scipy.nan).encode("hex_codec")
'7ff8000000000000'
```

Referring to [Kevin's Summary Charts](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs341/IEEE-754references.html#kevin_chart), that shows that `float('nan')` is actually technically the Indeterminate value, while `scipy.nan` is a Quiet NaN.

Let's try making a Signaling NaN, and then verify it.

```
>>> try_signaling_nan = struct.unpack(">d", "\x7f\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01")[0]
>>> struct.pack(">d", try_signaling_nan).encode("hex_codec")
'7ff8000000000001'
```

No, the Signaling NaN gets converted to a Quiet NaN.

Now let's try making a Quiet NaN directly, and then verify it.

```
>>> try_quiet_nan = struct.unpack(">d", "\x7f\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")[0]
>>> struct.pack(">d", try_quiet_nan).encode("hex_codec")
'7ff8000000000000'
```

So that's how to make a proper Quiet NaN using `struct.unpack()`--at least, on a Windows platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stigma. I've taken the liberty of editing it to add code samples. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad you got out of it what you needed, and thank you for adding the code samples for others like myself to learn from. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if `float('nan')` is always one or the other when you change systems, but you can get the other nan by running `-float('nan')`. Also, in Python 3.5+, your code to view the hex repr needs to be `struct.pack(">d", float('nan')).hex()`.

Answer (score 5):

**CPython definition of nan**

When Python reports a `nan`, where does that come from?

- Result of a calculation (platform specific values?)
- `Py_NAN` in the CPython C source code

  - defined as `(Py_HUGE_VAL * 0.)`

    - Value is platform-specific
    - `Py_HUGE_VAL` is probably defined as `HUGE_VAL`--it has a note to say it should be `HUGE_VAL` except on platforms where that is broken.
- `float('nan')` which is defined from `Py_NAN` in CPython's C source code.

**Reading Python and pywin32 Source Code**

I've had a look at the C source code for `pywin32`, in particular `win32com`, which forms the Python↔COM translation layer. That code:

- takes the input object
- calls `PyNumber_Float()` to convert it to a Python `float` (if it isn't already)
- calls `PyFloat_AsDouble()` to convert it to a plain C `double` value.

  - This simply returns the C `double` directly contained in the `PyFloatObject` member `ob_fval`.

So it looks as though I've traced a `NaN` from the COM interface back to a plain C `double` type containing `Py_NAN`, whatever that turns out to be on the Windows platform.

**TestStand NAN Value**

Now I've tried this with NI TestStand. First I tried:

```
quiet_nan = struct.unpack(">d", "\x7f\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01")[0]
# Set the variable's value in TestStand
locals_prop_object.SetValNumber(var_name, 0, quiet_nan)
```

But that still appeared in TestStand as `IND`. So then I created a TestStand file with variables set to `IND` and `NAN`, and read the values from Python. It turns out that TestStand's `NAN` has a value of `FFFF000000000001`. According to [Kevin's Summary Charts](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs341/IEEE-754references.html#kevin_chart) that is a *negative* quiet NAN. TestStand's `IND` does have the expected value for *Indeterminate*, `FFF8000000000000`.

**Success**

So, after all that, I have succeeded in setting a NAN in TestStand, from Python:

```
# Make a NAN suitable for TestStand
teststand_nan = struct.unpack(">d", "\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01")[0]
# Set the variable's value in TestStand
locals_prop_object.SetValNumber(var_name, 0, teststand_nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

John Cook had a nice post on this that might be helpful:

- [IEEE floating point arithmetic in Python](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/21/ieee-arithmetic-python/)

*Update*: won't this work?

```
In [144]: import scipy

In [145]: scipy.nan
Out[145]: 1.#QNAN

In [146]: scipy.inf
Out[146]: 1.#INF

In [147]: scipy.inf * 0
Out[147]: -1.#IND
```

Comment: You probably intended to link [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/21/ieee-arithmetic-python/).

Comment: That's a helpful reference for learning about NAN and INF in Python. Unfortunately, it doesn't go as far as answering my question.

Comment: `scipy.nan` sounds interesting. Note, on Windows, it is printed simply as `nan`. So if you get `1.#QNAN` I assume you're on Linux. Unfortunately, I'm home sick today, and I have a Windows laptop but it doesn't have TestStand on it to try this.

Comment: I'm on Windows Vista with python 2.5, scipy 0.8. Not sure if it makes a difference, but it's 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, it seems there is some confusion as to thinking that the sign of a `NaN` determines whether or not it is quiet. On the contrary, the convention is that the most significant bit of the mantissa determines this. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding) (emphasis added):

> In IEEE 754 standard-conforming floating-point storage formats, NaNs are identified by specific, pre-defined bit patterns unique to NaNs. *The sign bit does not matter*. Binary format NaNs are represented with the exponential field filled with ones (like infinity values), and some non-zero number in the significand field (to make them distinct from infinity values). The original IEEE 754 standard from 1985 (IEEE 754-1985) only described binary floating-point formats, and did not specify how the signaling/quiet state was to be tagged. In practice, the most significant bit of the significand field determined whether a NaN is signaling or quiet... The 2008 revision of the IEEE 754 standard (IEEE 754-2008) makes formal recommendations for the encoding of the signaling/quiet state. *For binary formats, the most significant bit of the significand field should be an 'is_quiet' flag. I.e. this bit is non-zero if the NaN is quiet, and zero if the NaN is signaling*.

Since most implementations are IEEE 754-2008 conformant, this is the convention you should follow. In general, you cannot plan on the sign bit being consistent for NaNs, even for different NaNs on the same platform. Under this convention, `float('nan')` and `scipy.nan` both seem to be quiet NaNs, at least in the cases discussed above.

Comment: It seems that NI TestStand has unconventional interpretation of the different types of NaN. At least, it did when I was asking this question. I haven't used TestStand in the last 7 years.