# Trapping quiet NaN

Tags: c++, debugging, x86, floating-point

I have an application where some component occasionally inserts a qNaN in a large data stream, which then invalidates the entire processing (FFT on a vector containing a single qNaN results in an all-qNaN output). Now I'd like to catch that component in the act and find out why it's doing that.

For this, I'd need to somehow make all NaNs signalling during debug. Is there a way to do so, with a x64 CPU executing 32 bit code?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but lots of details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c

Comment: Another question with good details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247447/usefulness-of-signaling-nan

Comment: Related: [Can I make gcc tell me when a calculation results in NaN or inf at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941611/can-i-make-gcc-tell-me-when-a-calculation-results-in-nan-or-inf-at-runtime/20973509)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trace a NaN in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615724/how-to-trace-a-nan-in-c)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to make all NaNs, overflows, and zerodivides signaling during debug, it is possible.

For gcc:

```
#include <fenv.h>

#ifndef NDEBUG
feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
#endif
```

For Visual Studio (not tested):

```
#include <float.h>

#ifndef NDEBUG
_clearfp();
_controlfp(_controlfp(0, 0) & ~(_EM_INVALID | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW),
           _MCW_EM);
#endif
```

References: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh%28VS.80%29.aspx), [gcc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feenableexcept).

---

These functions allow to catch either NaNs, produced by floating point operations (overflows, zerodivides, invalid operations), or sNaNs, used as input to some floating point operation. They do not allow to catch qNaNs, used as input to floating point operation. For such qNaNs, the only way to find them is to check each value individually (see Luchian Grigore's answer).

So if the component, that inserts a qNaN is in the same program, were you want to catch it, or if this component is in separate program, but you have its source codes, just enable FP exceptions with `feenableexcept()`/`_controlfp()`. Otherwise, check every value in the incoming data stream with `isnan()` (C++11) or with `x != x`.

Comment: Do you put this in the implementation file?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, yes, just call this from main().

Comment: Hm, still didn't get an exception, but accepting as it put me on the right track with debugging.

Comment: If you really need an exception, there is a way. But very slow and complicated. You can write driver (kernel module), set "EM" flag in "CR0" control register, and get an exception on every FP operation. Then check for qNaN and perform operation in kernel mode.

Comment: Or you can try to patch 387-emulation code to simplify this task.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there's a way to put a data breakpoint all over the memory to catch *all* `NaNs`.

I'd look for the code that inserts into the `vector` and test for `NaN` there:

```
if ( x != x )
    assert(!"NaN detected");
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't put the condition in the `assert` itself?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did think about it, but it's more readable to the untrained eye like this.

Comment: This is a valuable opportunity to train that eye.