# What is the difference between quiet NaN and signaling NaN?

Tags: floating-point, nan, ieee-754

I have read about floating-point and I understand that NaN could result from operations. But I can't understand what these are concepts exactly. What is the difference between them?

Which one can be produced during C++ programming? As a programmer, could I write a program that causes an sNaN?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

When an operation results in a quiet NaN, there is no indication that anything is unusual until the program checks the result and sees a NaN.  That is, computation continues without any signal from the floating point unit (FPU) or library if floating-point is implemented in software.  A signalling NaN will produce a signal, usually in the form of exception from the FPU.  Whether the exception is thrown depends on the state of the FPU.

C++11 adds a few language [controls over the floating-point environment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) and provides [standardized ways to create and test for NaNs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan).  However, whether the controls are implemented is not well standardized and floating-point exceptions are not typically caught the same way as standard C++ exceptions.

In POSIX/Unix systems, floating point exceptions are typically caught using a handler for [SIGFPE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html).

Comment: Adding to this: Generally, the purpose of a signaling NaN (sNaN) is for debugging. For example, floating-point objects might be initialized to sNaN. Then, if the program fails to one of them a value before using it, an exception will occur when the program uses the sNaN in an arithmetic operation. A program will not produce an sNaN inadvertently; no normal operations produce sNaNs. They are only created specifically for the purpose of having a signaling NaN, not as the result of any arithmetic.

Comment: In contrast, NaNs are for more normal programming. They can be produced by normal operations when there is no numerical result (e.g., taking the square root of a negative number when the result must be real). Their purpose is generally to allow arithmetic to proceed somewhat normally. E.g., you might have a huge array of numbers, some of which represent special cases that cannot be handled normally. You can call a complicated function to process this array, and it could operate on the array with usual arithmetic, ignoring NaNs. After it ends, you would separate the special cases for more work.

Comment: @wrdieter Thank you, then only najor difference is generating exeption or not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for your attention to second piece of question.

Comment: @JalalJaberi yes, the exception is the main difference

Comment: Ugh... It is sad that this question had to be answered outside the documentation for C++.  Thank you!

Answer (score 86):

**How qNaNs and sNaNs look like experimentally?**

Let's first learn how to identify if we have an sNaN or a qNaN.

I'll be using C++ in this answer instead of C because it offers the convenient [`std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) and [`std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN) which I could not find in C conveniently.

I could not however find a function to classify if a NaN is sNaN or qNaN, so let's just print out the NaN raw bytes:

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath> // nanf, isnan
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

void print_float(float f) {
    std::uint32_t i;
    std::memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof f);
    std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::has_quiet_NaN, "");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::has_signaling_NaN, "");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity, "");

    // Generate them.
    float qnan = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    float snan = std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN();
    float inf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    float nan0 = std::nanf("0");
    float nan1 = std::nanf("1");
    float nan2 = std::nanf("2");
    float div_0_0 = 0.0f / 0.0f;
    float sqrt_negative = std::sqrt(-1.0f);

    // Print their bytes.
    std::cout << "qnan "; print_float(qnan);
    std::cout << "snan "; print_float(snan);
    std::cout << " inf "; print_float(inf);
    std::cout << "-inf "; print_float(-inf);
    std::cout << "nan0 "; print_float(nan0);
    std::cout << "nan1 "; print_float(nan1);
    std::cout << "nan2 "; print_float(nan2);
    std::cout << " 0/0 "; print_float(div_0_0);
    std::cout << "sqrt "; print_float(sqrt_negative);

    // Assert if they are NaN or not.
    assert(std::isnan(qnan));
    assert(std::isnan(snan));
    assert(!std::isnan(inf));
    assert(!std::isnan(-inf));
    assert(std::isnan(nan0));
    assert(std::isnan(nan1));
    assert(std::isnan(nan2));
    assert(std::isnan(div_0_0));
    assert(std::isnan(sqrt_negative));
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

output on my x86_64 machine:

```
qnan 7fc00000
snan 7fa00000
 inf 7f800000
-inf ff800000
nan0 7fc00000
nan1 7fc00001
nan2 7fc00002
 0/0 ffc00000
sqrt ffc00000
```

We can also execute the program on aarch64 with QEMU user mode:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/ main.out
```

and that produces the exact same output, suggesting that multiple archs closely implement IEEE 754.

At this point, if you are not familiar with the structure of IEEE 754 floating point numbers, have a look at: [What is a subnormal floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428)

In binary some of the values above are:

```
     31
     |
     | 30    23 22                    0
     | |      | |                     |
-----+-+------+-+---------------------+
qnan 0 11111111 10000000000000000000000
snan 0 11111111 01000000000000000000000
 inf 0 11111111 00000000000000000000000
-inf 1 11111111 00000000000000000000000
-----+-+------+-+---------------------+
     | |      | |                     |
     | +------+ +---------------------+
     |    |               |
     |    v               v
     | exponent        fraction
     |
     v
     sign
```

From this experiment we observe that:

- qNaN and sNaN seem to be differentiated only by bit 22: 1 means quiet, and 0 means signaling
- infinities are also quite similar with exponent == 0xFF, but they have fraction == 0.

  For this reason, NaNs must set bit 21 to 1, otherwise it would not be possible to distinguish sNaN from positive infinity!
- `nanf()` produces several different NaNs, so there must be multiple possible encodings:

  ```
  7fc00000
  7fc00001
  7fc00002
  ```

  Since `nan0` is the same as `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()`, we deduce that they are all different quiet NaNs.

  The [C11 N1570 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) confirms that `nanf()` generates quiet NaNs, because `nanf` forwards to `strtod` and 7.22.1.3 "The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions" says:

  > A character sequence NAN or NAN(n-char-sequence opt ) is interpreted as a quiet
  >   NaN, if supported in the return type, else like a subject sequence part that does not have
  >   the expected form; the meaning of the n-char sequence is implementation-defined. 293)

See also:

- [How to produce a NaN float in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212356/how-to-produce-a-nan-float-in-c)
- [C/C++ NaN constant (literal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691207/c-c-nan-constant-literal)

**How qNaNs and sNaNs look like in the manuals?**

[IEEE 754 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) recommends that (TODO mandatory or optional?):

- anything with exponent == 0xFF and fraction != 0 is a NaN
- and that the highest fraction bit differentiates qNaN from sNaN

but it does not seem to say which bit is preferred to differentiate infinity from NaN.

6.2.1 "NaN encodings in binary formats" says:

> This subclause further specifies the encodings of NaNs as bit strings when they are the results of operations.
>   When encoded, all NaNs have a sign bit and a pattern of bits necessary to identify the encoding as a NaN
>   and which determines its kind (sNaN vs. qNaN). The remaining bits, which are in the trailing significand
>   field, encode the payload, which might be diagnostic information (see above).
>   34
>
> All binary NaN bit strings have all the bits of the biased exponent field E set to 1 (see 3.4). A quiet NaN bit
>   string should be encoded with the first bit (d1) of the trailing significand field T being 1. A signaling NaN
>   bit string should be encoded with the first bit of the trailing significand field being 0. If the first bit of the
>   trailing significand field is 0, some other bit of the trailing significand field must be non-zero to distinguish
>   the NaN from infinity. In the preferred encoding just described, a signaling NaN shall be quieted by setting
>   d1 to 1, leaving the remaining bits of T unchanged.
>   For binary formats, the payload is encoded in the p−2 least significant bits of the trailing significand field

The [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual - Volume 1 Basic Architecture -  253665-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081316/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) 4.8.3.4 "NaNs" confirms that x86 follows IEEE 754 by distinguishing NaN and sNaN by the highest fraction bit:

> The IA-32 architecture defines two classes of NaNs: quiet NaNs (QNaNs) and signaling NaNs (SNaNs). A QNaN is a NaN with the most significant fraction bit set an SNaN is a NaN with the most significant fraction bit clear.

and so does the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual - ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile - DDI 0487C.a](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf) A1.4.3 "Single-precision floating-point format":

`fraction != 0`: The value is a NaN, and is either a quiet NaN or a signaling NaN. The two types of NaN are distinguished by their most significant fraction bit, bit[22]:

- `bit[22] == 0`: The NaN is a signaling NaN. The sign bit can take any value, and the remaining fraction bits can take any value except all zeros.
- `bit[22] == 1`: The NaN is a quiet NaN. The sign bit and remaining fraction bits can take any value.

**How are qNanS and sNaNs generated?**

One major difference between qNaNs and sNaNs is that:

- qNaN is generated by regular built-in (software or hardware) arithmetic operations with weird values
- sNaN is never generated by built-in operations, it can only be explicitly added by programmers, e.g. with `std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN`

I could not find clear IEEE 754 or C11 quotes for that, but neither can I find any built-in operation that generates sNaNs ;-)

The Intel manual clearly states this principle however at 4.8.3.4 "NaNs":

> SNaNs are typically used to trap or invoke an exception handler. They must be inserted by software; that is, the processor never generates an SNaN as a result of a floating-point operation.

This can be seen from our example where both:

```
float div_0_0 = 0.0f / 0.0f;
float sqrt_negative = std::sqrt(-1.0f);
```

produce exactly the same bits as `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()`.

Both of those operations compile to a single x86 assembly instruction that generates the qNaN directly in the hardware (TODO confirm with GDB).

**What do qNaNs and sNaNs do differently?**

Now that we know what qNaNs and sNaNs look like, and how to manipulate them, we are finally ready to try and make sNaNs do their thing and blow some programs up!

So without further ado:

blow_up.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath> // isnan
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits
#include <unistd.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main() {
    float snan = std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN();
    float qnan = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    float f;

    // No exceptions.
    assert(std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT) == 0);

    // Still no exceptions because qNaN.
    f = qnan + 1.0f;
    assert(std::isnan(f));
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT) == FE_INVALID)
        std::cout << "FE_ALL_EXCEPT qnan + 1.0f" << std::endl;

    // Now we can get an exception because sNaN, but signals are disabled.
    f = snan + 1.0f;
    assert(std::isnan(f));
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT) == FE_INVALID)
        std::cout << "FE_ALL_EXCEPT snan + 1.0f" << std::endl;
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

    // And now we enable signals and blow up with SIGFPE! >:-)
    feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);
    f = qnan + 1.0f;
    std::cout << "feenableexcept qnan + 1.0f" << std::endl;
    f = snan + 1.0f;
    std::cout << "feenableexcept snan + 1.0f" << std::endl;
}
```

Compile, run and get the exit status:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pthread -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -o blow_up.out blow_up.cpp -lm -lrt
./blow_up.out
echo $?
```

Output:

```
FE_ALL_EXCEPT snan + 1.0f
feenableexcept qnan + 1.0f
Floating point exception (core dumped)
136
```

Note that this behaviour only happens with `-O0` in GCC 8.2: with `-O3`, GCC pre-calculates and optimizes all our sNaN operations away! I'm not sure if there is a standard compliant way of preventing that.

So we deduce from this example that:

- `snan + 1.0` causes `FE_INVALID`, but `qnan + 1.0` does not
- Linux only generates a signal if it is enabled with `feenableexept`.

  This is a glibc extension, I could not find any way to do that in any standard.

When the signal happens, it because the CPU hardware itself raises an exception, which the Linux kernel handled and informed the application through the signal.

The outcome is that bash prints `Floating point exception (core dumped)`, and the exit status is `136`, which [corresponds to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/default-exit-code-when-process-is-terminated) signal `136 - 128 == 8`, which according to:

```
man 7 signal
```

is `SIGFPE`.

Note that `SIGFPE` is the same signal that we get if we try to divide an integer by 0:

```
int main() {
    int i = 1 / 0;
}
```

although for integers:

- dividing anything by zero raises the signal, since there is no infinity representation in integers
- the signal it happens by default, without the need for `feenableexcept`

**How to handle the SIGFPE?**

If you just create a handler that returns normally, it leads to an infinite loop, because after the handler returns, the division happens again! This can be verified with GDB.

The only way is to use `setjmp` and `longjmp` to jump somewhere else as shown at: [C handle signal SIGFPE and continue execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431879/c-handle-signal-sigfpe-and-continue-execution/39431923#39431923)

**What are some real world applications of sNaNs?**

Quite honestly, I still haven't understood a super useful use case for sNaNs, this has been asked at: [Usefulness of signaling NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247447/usefulness-of-signaling-nan)

sNaNs feel particularly useless because we can detect the initial invalid operations (`0.0f/0.0f`) that generate qNaNs with `feenableexcept`: it appears that `snan` just raises errors for more operations which `qnan` does not raise for, e.g. (`qnan + 1.0f`).

E.g.:

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argv;
    float f0 = 0.0;

    if (argc == 1) {
        feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);
    }
    float f1 = 0.0 / f0;
    printf("f1 %f\n", f1);

    feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);
    float f2 = f1 + 1.0;
    printf("f2 %f\n", f2);
}
```

compile:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c -lm
```

then:

```
./main.out
```

gives:

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

and:

```
./main.out  1
```

gives:

```
f1 -nan
f2 -nan
```

See also: [How to trace a NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615724/how-to-trace-a-nan-in-c/3616017#3616017)

**What are the signal flags and how are they manipulated?**

Everything is implemented in the CPU hardware.

The flags live in some register, and so does the bit that says if an exception / signal should be raised.

Those registers are [accessible from userland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems/44483439#44483439) from most archs.

This part of the glibc 2.29 code is actually very easy to understand!

For example, `fetestexcept` is implemented for x86_86 at [sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/ftestexcept.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/ftestexcept.c;h=f0a5344f061cfd5328f6a3b8f984fb5d85c96982;hb=56c86f5dd516284558e106d04b92875d5b623b7a):

```
#include <fenv.h>

int
fetestexcept (int excepts)
{
  int temp;
  unsigned int mxscr;

  /* Get current exceptions.  */
  __asm__ ("fnstsw %0\n"
       "stmxcsr %1" : "=m" (*&temp), "=m" (*&mxscr));

  return (temp | mxscr) & excepts & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;
}
libm_hidden_def (fetestexcept)
```

so we immediately see that the instructions use is [`stmxcsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stmxcsr) which stands for "Store MXCSR Register State".

And `feenableexcept` is implemented at [sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/feenablxcpt.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/feenablxcpt.c;h=d166bfcf31d2804e3a403427782caaaa9ac4dac8;hb=56c86f5dd516284558e106d04b92875d5b623b7a):

```
#include <fenv.h>

int
feenableexcept (int excepts)
{
  unsigned short int new_exc, old_exc;
  unsigned int new;

  excepts &= FE_ALL_EXCEPT;

  /* Get the current control word of the x87 FPU.  */
  __asm__ ("fstcw %0" : "=m" (*&new_exc));

  old_exc = (~new_exc) & FE_ALL_EXCEPT;

  new_exc &= ~excepts;
  __asm__ ("fldcw %0" : : "m" (*&new_exc));

  /* And now the same for the SSE MXCSR register.  */
  __asm__ ("stmxcsr %0" : "=m" (*&new));

  /* The SSE exception masks are shifted by 7 bits.  */
  new &= ~(excepts << 7);
  __asm__ ("ldmxcsr %0" : : "m" (*&new));

  return old_exc;
}
```

**What does the C standard say about qNaN vs sNaN?**

The [C11 N1570 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) explicitly says that the standard does not differentiate between them at F.2.1 "Infinities, signed zeros, and NaNs":

> 1 This specification does not define the behavior of signaling NaNs. It generally uses the term NaN to denote quiet NaNs. The NAN and INFINITY macros and the nan functions in `<math.h>` provide designations for IEC 60559 NaNs and infinities.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2. GitHub upstreams:

- [c/nan.c](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/671e4c164f809902f236a8912e0eb000f40b1617/c/nan.c)
- [cpp/nan.cpp](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/671e4c164f809902f236a8912e0eb000f40b1617/cpp/nan.cpp)
- [glibc/interactive/feenableexcept.c](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/671e4c164f809902f236a8912e0eb000f40b1617/glibc/interactive/feenableexcept.cpp)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Interchange_formats points out that IEEE-754 merely *suggests* that 0 for signaling NaNs is a good implementation choice, to allow quieting a NaN without risking making it an infinity (significand=0).  Apparently that's not standardized, although it is what x86 does.  (And the fact that it's the MSB of the significand that determines qNaN vs. sNaN *is* standardized).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format says x86 and ARM are the same, but PA-RISC made the opposite choice.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I'm not sure what the "should" == "must" or "is preferred" in IEEE 754 20at "A signaling NaN bit string should be encoded with the first bit of the trailing significand field being 0".

Comment: re: *but it does not seem to specify which bit should be used to differentiate infinity from NaN.*  You wrote that like you expected there to be some specific bit that the standard recommends setting to distinguish sNaN from infinity.  IDK why you'd expect there to be any such bit; any non-zero choice is fine.  Just pick something that later identifies where the sNaN came from.  IDK, just sounds like weird phrasing, and my first impression when reading it was that you were saying that web page didn't describe what distinguishes inf from NaN in the encoding (an all-zero significand).

Comment: Before 2008, IEEE 754 said which is the signaling/quiet bit (bit 22) but not which value specified what.  Most processors had converged on 1 = quiet, so that was made part of the standard in the 2008 edition.  It says "should" rather than "must" to avoid making older implementations that made the same choice non-conformant.  In general, "should" in a standard means "must, unless you have very compelling (and preferably well-documented) reasons for not complying".