# Maximum value of 64 bit floating point number for overflow detection

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I have a seemingly simple problem: I want to detect whether a floating point addition in Fortran will overflow by doing something like the following:

```
real*8 :: a, b, c

a = ! some value
b = ! some value

if (b > DOUBLE_MAX - a) then
  ! handle overflow
else
  c = a + b
```

The problem is that I don't know what `DOUBLE_MAX` should be. I'm aware of how floating point numbers are represented according to IEEE 754 but the largest value representable by a double precision floating point number seems to be too large for a variable of type `real*8` (i.e. if I try to assign `1.7976931348623157e+308` to such a variable gfortran complains). C and C++ have predefined constants/generic functions for this purpose but I couldn't find a Fortran equivalent.

Note: I'm aware that `real*8` is not *really* part of the standard but there seems to be no other way to reliably specify that a floating point number should use the double precision format.

Comment: I looked for a duplicate here but didn't find it, although I expected to be able to find one. There are lots of posts including 'huge' as a phrase, unfortunately. Feel free to point this to a duplicate instead and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: *"there seems to be no other way to reliably specify that a floating point number should use the double precision"* There are several ways, but `real*8` is NOT one of them. It specifies a real with 8 bytes of storage size, not double precision in any meaning I am aware of. For Fortran double precision use `double precision` or a kind constant set to `kind(1.0_dp)`. If you want the IEEE double precision floating type, use the IEEE module, do not use `real*8`, that guarantees nothing.

Comment: Strictly real*8 specifies and guarantees nothing at all, it may not even compile, not being Fortran. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter to see how you should be doing it, please throw this archaic extension in the bin.

Comment: You might also want to look at standard Fortran's way of handling Floating point exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
real(REAL64) function func( a, b )
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: REAL64, INT64
  use, intrinsic :: ieee_arithmetic, only: ieee_value, ieee_set_flag, IEEE_OVERFLOW, IEEE_QUIET_NAN
  implicit none
  real(REAL64), intent(in) :: a, b
  real(REAL64), parameter  :: MAX64 = huge(0.0_REAL64)

  if ( b > MAX64-a ) then
    ! Set IEEE_OVERFLOW flag and return NaN
    call ieee_set_flag(IEEE_OVERFLOW,.true.)
    func = ieee_value(func,IEEE_QUIET_NAN)
  else
    func = a + b
  end if

  return
end function func
```

All I could find for intrinsic `ieee_exceptions` module is:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgfortran/ieee/ieee_exceptions.F90

For setting NaN value see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971836/having-parameter-constant-variable-with-nan-value-in-fortran).

Comment: ieee_value (as in the link) is a cleaner way of setting the NAN value. Also I think I would do the addition and then test for the overflow rather than as written, it just feels as though I am making less assumptions about the floating point implementation that way.

Comment: @Ian Bush indeed it is much cleaner way. I changed to `ieee_value`...

Comment: Neat, but isn't REAL64 only available from Fortran 2003?

Comment: Nvm, this at least seems to compile with a Fortran 95 compiler so I'll accept this as the correct way to do what I want. And @IanBush: You're suggesting checking for overflow with `ieee_get_flag`, right? That seems more reasonable.

Comment: Yes  - I'd do the addition and use ieee_get_flag (and also make sure about the halting mode). I'd also probably use ieee_selected_real_kind as well. And all this is Fortran 2003, which is the standard you should be using nowadays

Answer (score 2):

There are likely better ways to detect overflow, but the precise answer to your question is to use the `huge` function. `HUGE(a)` returns the largest possible number representable by the type `a`.