# reinterpret int32 to float

Tags: c++, x86, nan, reinterpret-cast

I need to save a float value which is a copied-memory from an integer value.
In `reinterpretedFloat` function, I made an sample integer and copy the memory to a float variable.
The thing is **the value changes when the memcpy-ed float returns**.

Here is the sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printHex(const unsigned char* buff, int count)
{
    printf("0X");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("\t%X", buff[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

float reinterpretedFloat()
{
    int32_t value = 0x7F845E58;
    float tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, &value, sizeof(float));
    printHex(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&tmp), 4); //memcpy
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    float newFloat = reinterpretedFloat();
    printHex(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&newFloat), 4); //returned value

    return 0;
}
```

This is the result.

```
0X      58      5E      84      7F(memcpy)
0X      58      5E      C4      7F(returned value)
```

What I expected was `0X 58 5E 84 7F`...

Any body can explain why this is happening?
In x64 configuration, this does not happens.

Comment: Is `sizeof(float)==sizeof(int32_t)` when you compile on x64?

Comment: @tadman yes. they are same size.

Comment: You're saying this only happens in x86 configuration?

Comment: I can reproduce this on an x86_64 machine with clang and compiling with `-m32`. This happens at optimization levels 0 and 1, but is not reproduced at optimization levels 2 and above. `0x7F845E58` is nan, which I suspect is the ultimate root cause.

Comment: It is NaN, there are multiple NaN representations.  Unclear how this happened, you can't reliably round-trip a 32-bit integer through a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0x7f845e58 is a [signaling NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN). It gets normalized to 0x7fc45e58, which is a quiet NaN with the same payload.

The difference between x86-64 and 32-bit x86 outcomes is because in the former mode, to return the `float` value from `reinterpretedFloat()` function, `MOVSS` instruction from the [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) ISA extension loads the value into `xmm0` register without any conversions, while on the latter, `FLD dword [...]` is used, which converts from 32-bit `float` to [x87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87)'s internal 80-bit `long double` format, normalizing the signaling status to quiet*.

The difference in mechanism is due to the fact that x86-64 architecture guarantees support for SSE, so the ABI uses it, while i386 ABI doesn't require it, since not all x86 CPUs support it.

<sub>* Technically, the conversion causes an Invalid Operation exception, but since it's masked (by default), you get the normalized result of removing signaling status from the NaN</sub>

Comment: One resource I found useful for this was [Table 2-8: Values Represented by Bit Patterns (x86)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html).

Comment: @Ruslan What do you mean by signaling NaN?

Comment: @JaeJunLEE: [What is difference between quiet NaN and signaling NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18118408/1287251)